# Unable to fetch complete records from Salesforce using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, salesforce, aws-sdk

I am trying to fetch the data from salesforce using the `simple_salesforce` library in python.

I am able to get the correct count of records while running the count query.

But while I am trying to put that results (in the form of list) into s3 as a JSON object, not as many reocrds are getting persisted as I captured from Salesforce.

Here is the piece of code:

```
result = sf.query("SELECT ID FROM Opportunity")['records']
object.put(Body=(bytes(json.dumps(result, indent=2).encode('UTF-8'))))
```

Is the problem on the Salesforce side or am I running into an issue using AWS's SDK to put the objects into S3?

Comment: Could you show us the exact data you expected and the exact data you got?

Answer (score 0):

[Salesforce API returns stuff in chunks](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_query.htm), default is 2000 records at a time. If it'd return to you 1M records it could kill your memory usage. Retrieve a chunk, process it (save to file?), request next chunk.

It's straight on the [project's homepage](https://pypi.org/project/simple-salesforce/):

> If, due to an especially large result, Salesforce adds a
>   nextRecordsUrl to your query result, such as "nextRecordsUrl" :
>   "/services/data/v26.0/query/01gD0000002HU6KIAW-2000", you can pull the
>   additional results with either the ID or the full URL (if using the
>   full URL, you must pass ‘True’ as your second argument)

```
sf.query_more("01gD0000002HU6KIAW-2000")
sf.query_more("/services/data/v26.0/query/01gD0000002HU6KIAW-2000", True)
```

> As a convenience, to retrieve all of the results in a single local
>   method call use

```
sf.query_all("SELECT Id, Email FROM Contact WHERE LastName = 'Jones'")
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I have around 40,000 records and offset also works only for 2000 records. So once the first chunk i.e. 1 to 2000  records are fetched(or saved in some file), then how to fetch the next chunk.

Comment: No, not the offset. `SELECT ... LIMIT 2000 OFFSET 2000` changes your query and the result set. When you have a bigger query salesforce opens a "cursor" in underlying Oracle database and you can travel with it (API queries only forward but in Apex code you can go next page, previous page, first, last...). Really, check SF REST API documentation for this `nextRecordsUrl`. Or do `sf.query_all`