# Salesforce API Python - fetching large amount of data in batches

Tags: python, salesforce

Is there any way I can fetch millions of records from a salesforce DB.The problem is, unlike in Oracle, we cannot use offset-limit loop by ordering the table and fetching each partition. The maximum offset that can be applied is 2000 is salesforce. Due to this I cannot skip more than 2000 rows which means I cannot fetch rows above that limit.

Answer (score 2):

You absolutely can. Which API do you use and do you issue raw HTTP requests or do you use a Salesforce Python library.

Have you seen [How to handle an offset greater than 2000 on SOQL without sorting by ID or date using the Salesforce Rest API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56447511/313628) and [Unable to fetch complete records from Salesforce using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57590301/313628)

You can even use bulk API v2 to pull data in 10K chunks: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_bulk_v2.meta/api_bulk_v2/queries.htm

It's implemented in [simple-salesforce](https://pypi.org/project/simple-salesforce/) as

```
query = 'SELECT Id, Name FROM Account LIMIT 10'
sf.bulk.Account.query(query)
```

Comment: Yeah, its the python salesforce API. The connection object is a pandaforce login object.  The problem is if the data volume is much large (Millions) I cannot efficiently partition them. So I hope the only thing I can do is use the primary key (Id) to filter the data. Like at each iteration fetch disjoint sets of data using proper where Id < and >  conditions. I have a 32 GB server but when data volume is greater than million, it goes to memory error. I'll go through what you've provided. Thanks

Comment: SF works more like Oracle cursors than OFFSETs all the way. Yes, please check the resources. Don't know how smart that pandaforce thing is but at the very least you have `nextRecordsUrl` you can google for. Sounds like it tries to call it internally, fetch whole result set before returning to your code, even if that means exhausting memory. Maybe there's a flag you can use to make it simply work in chunks as they're received.